# Error with apr-util while installing httpd 2.4.1 on centos

Tags: apache, apr

I am trying to install httpd-2.4.1 on my CentOS machine (it has 2.2.15 currently). I did the following...

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install perl
sudo yum install libbz2 libbz2-devel
sudo yum install bzip2-devel
sudo yum install curl-devel
sudo yum install libjpeg-devel
sudo yum install libpng-devel
sudo yum install libX11-devel gd-devel
sudo yum install libc-client-devel
sudo yum install libmcrypt-devel
sudo yum install bzip2
sudo yum install pcre-devel
sudo yum install openssl-devel
sudo yum install libxml2-devel
sudo yum install libmcrypt

#apache
wget http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/apache//apr/apr-util-1.4.1.tar.gz
wget http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/apache//apr/apr-1.4.6.tar.gz
extract and move to /srclib in httpd-2.4.1 directory
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so --enable-mods-shared=most --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util --enable-load-all-modules 
sudo make
sudo make install
```

And here I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/apache/lib/libexpat.a(xmlparse.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/apache/lib/libexpat.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: install: error: relink `libaprutil-1.la' with the above command before installing it
```

How do I relink libaprutil-1.la with the above command? (i am guessing it refers to -fPIC?)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include `--with-included-apr-util`  while running `./configure`

Comment: yes, i noticed. I tried again after including it, same problem. Made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

./configure --with-included-apr --with-included-apr-util